# Difference between --xz and --lzma in GNU tar?

Tags: tar, compression

As far as I can tell, XZ is a container that uses the LZMA2 algorithm (i.e. extended LZMA); but e.g.

```
$ xz foo/
```

complains about `foo/` being a directory. So presumably the correct way to preserve directories with XZ is with `tar`; then what is the difference between `tar --lzma` and `tar --xz`?

(Note that I do explicitly want ownership and permissions preserved, which is why I'm not just using 7z.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This options control which external binary tar calls for compressing its data stream: `lzma` and `xz` respectively. While both of them uses the same compression algorithm by default, `xz` is considered more up-to-date and feature rich, with `lzma` being somewhat legacy tool. Modern version of `xz-utils` provides both commands, with `lzma` being an 'alias' for `xz --format=lzma` (`man xz`).

Comment: So with modern `xz-utils`, there's effectively no difference?

Comment: I believe so, at least when using with `tar`. `xz` archives can be concatenated, while `lzma` cannot (limitations of container format) — that's the only notable difference for me, applying `xz` was used with lzma compression.